# SetCountry() does not reflect in backend

Tags: magento2, api, customer-address

So practically, i'm importing data over API and saving it like this :

(not all the code but only the relevant)

```
$addressarray
    ->setCustomAttribute('exact_address_id', $contactaddress['ID'])
    ->setCustomerId($customerrep->getId())
    ->setFirstname($contact['firstname'])
    ->setLastname($contact['lastname'])
    ->setCountryId($contactaddress['Country'])
    ->setRegionId(0)
    ->setPostcode($contactaddress['Postcode'])
    ->setCity($contactaddress['City'])
    ->setTelephone($contact['account']['Phone'])
    ->setFax($contact['account']['Fax'])
    ->setCompany($contactaddress['AccountName'])
    ->setStreet(array($contactaddressstreet))
    ->setVatId($contact['account']['VATNumber']);

    if ($contact['account']['AddressLine1'] == $contactaddress['AddressLine1']) {
    $addressarray->setIsDefaultBilling(true);
    $addressarray->setIsDefaultShipping(true);
    } else {
    $addressarray->setIsDefaultBilling(false);
    $addressarray->setIsDefaultShipping(false);
    }
    try {
    $address->save($addressarray);
```

And everything seems to work fine , everything is filled in and in the database addresses are created.

BUT

Even though my database table `customer_address_entity` says '`BE`' (which is id for Belgium) under `country_id` the field itself is empty.

Even more so when i save the customer myself with the address nothing really changes. Its still `BE`.

[image: address example]

Anyone any idea?

Github : [Github magento 2 report](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11018)

Answer (score 0):

Add below code  after `$address->save` and check

```
$address->setCountryId('BR');
$address->getResource()->saveAttribute($address, 'country_id');
```

Comment: Which address repository/interface/model are you using? Because i have ->save in addressRepository and i have setcountryID in addressinterface and get resource in address model. But you are using the same variable for all 3?

Comment: So you would set the country ID after the save?

Comment: yes, you should add this two lines after  save() function

Comment: those don't work because $addres  komes from $address = $this->_addressRepository; --> Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface; and that class does not have ->getResource() function.

Comment: So from which class do you advice me to extend from?